# Android: How to know the alias name of the keystore?

Tags: android, keystore

I have lost my keystore and did not keep any back up of it. I know this question has been asked before but I do not want to extract the password of the keystore. I know the password. I just want to know the alias name and any other details that I might have put in the keystore. Is that possible?

Also, I had developed the previous apk on Android Studio. Now Im using ADT to generate the signed apk. Will it matter with regards to the apk signature process?

Thanks

Comment: No. It's not possible.

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you answer the second part?

Comment: No. Doesn't matter you generate apk with any IDE but you must sign apk with the same Keystore.

Comment: I think I had used proguard in Studio. Can it be used in ADT too?

Comment: MD is right. Using the same details/same alias to generate a new keystore will only give you a different keystore. How did you lose your keystore in the first place? Corrupt hard drive?

Comment: I sold my old laptop where I had that keystore. I took only back up of my source code but not the keystore :(

Comment: Yes, Proguard can be used in ADT too, but that's not going to matter. If your keystore is lost, you'll have to republish your app on Google Play with a different package name and all your existing users of the previous version will be stuck on the previous version forever.